# Converting numeric data to character based on condition in R

Tags: r, character, numeric

I have a numeric data column of months, so I want to convert the column to character type while also changing the values to alphabets.

```
all_trips %>%
 as.character(all_trips$ride_months == 1) <- 'jan'
```

it gave an error of : Error in as.character(all_trips$ride_month == 1) <- "jan" :
could not find function "as.character<-"

Comment: In a magrittr/dplyr pipe you change values with `mutate`. Try `all_trips%>%mutate(ride_months = ifelse(ride_months == 1,  'jan', ride_months))`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the assignment with a simple merge, e.g.

```
all_trips <- data.frame(ride_months=sample(12,10))

table <- data.frame(month_num = seq(1,12,1), 
                    month_str = c("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "mai", "jun", 
                                  "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"))


df = merge(all_trips, table, by.x="ride_months", by.y="month_num", sort=FALSE)

   ride_months month_str
1            4       apr
2            5       mai
3            9       sep
4            7       jul
5            3       mar
6            1       jan
7           11       nov
8           10       oct
9            2       feb
10           8       aug
```

then you can just simply overwrite the old column in your dataframe. e.g.

```
all_trips$ride_months <- df$month_str
```

Answer (score 0):

```
all_trips <- data.frame(ride_months=sample(12,10))

all_trips %>%
  mutate(month_str = factor(ride_months, levels = 1:12, labels = month.abb))
```

if you just want to change ride_months it would be

```
all_trips %>%
  mutate(ride_months = factor(ride_months, levels = 1:12, labels = month.abb))
```

Comment: Interesting how several methods can get you your answer in sql. Thanks very much